# getting all child data from parent controller in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get all child data from parent controller to make edit on all of them , and i have make this function to get them ,

```
 public function edit($id = 'Contractors.id') {

    $contractor = $this->Contractors->get($id, [
        'contain' => ["ContractorsAttachments"]
    ]);
  $ContractorsAttachments = $this->Contractors->ContractorsAttachments->find()->where(['ContractorsAttachments.contractor_id', $id])->all();

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {


        $array_dif = array();


            if (!empty($this->request->data['contractors_attachments'])) {
            foreach ($this->request->data['contractors_attachments'] as $attach) {
                if (isset($attach['id']))
                    $array_dif[] = $attach['id'];
            }
        }

        $ContractorsAttachments = $this->Contractors->patchEntity($ContractorsAttachments, $this->request->data,[
            'associated' => ['ContractorsAttachments']
        ]);

        if ($this->Contractors->save($ContractorsAttachments)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The contractor has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The contractor could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $attachments = $this->Contractors->ContractorsAttachments->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
```

But It's back with all the data at the child table at each parent id !! , and I need it to back with only that condition 
where(['ContractorsAttachments.contractor_id', Contractors.id])

So , what's the wrong with my code !?

Comment: `$query = $this->Contractors->find()->contain([
    'ContractorsAttachments' => function ($q) {
       return $q
            ->select('*')
            ->where(['ContractorsAttachments.contractor_id' => $id]);
    }
]);`

Comment: I had get this error :
You are required to select the "ContractorsAttachments.contractor_id" field(s)

Comment: add use($id) after function ($q)

like this

"function($q) use ($id)"

Comment: $ContractorsAttachments = $this->Contractors->find()->contain([ 'ContractorsAttachments' => function ($q) use($id) { return $q ->select('*') ->where(['ContractorsAttachments.contractor_id' => $id]); } ]);
It's giving me the same error

Comment: @AlivetoDie Using `*` is neither supported, nor is it required.